# keycloak in docker, web app not able to connect

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak

I have keycloak running in Docker and have another container running a spring based java app that is attempting to connect to keycloak.  The error message I keep getting is: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided issuer of "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/someproject".  the realm name does exist in the keycloak DB.   I can curl to the above URL from any other container.  But the web app keeps giving me that message.  Any hints would help.   Thanks, Bill

Comment: is your app served in the browser and is this request made from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try to expose your keycloak container port and set provided issuer like this http://docker-host-ip:exposed-port/auth/realms/someproject